# ngrx/effects, middleware or meta-reducer

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, reducers, ngrx-effects

In the [Comprehensive introduction to ngrx/store](https://gist.github.com/btroncone/a6e4347326749f938510) it has been mentioned several times that

> Middleware has been removed in ngrx/store v2. Please see the meta-reducers section for how to create similar functionality.

My question is, since ngrx/effects is middleware (or is it not?) then are there or are there going to be any side-effects (pardon the pun) on this project?

Answer (score 1):

`ngrx/effects` library uses the idea of `meta-reducer`. I have not used `ngrx/effects` version 1 and thus cannot comment about it. However, starting version 2, that is how they are implemented. As an end-user, you should not notice any major breaking change.

An example use of meta-reducer is described in this blog post:
https://netbasal.com/implementing-a-meta-reducer-in-ngrx-store-4379d7e1020a